# Remove a part of string based on its given length with replaceAll in Java

Tags: java, string, collections

I know that there are different ways to solve this task, but I need a particular way using replaceAll() method. I just stuck with right condition in the expression.

So I have a method like this:

```
    public static void handleComments(List<Comment> comments, int maxTextLength) {
            comments.replaceAll(comment -> comment.getText().length() > maxTextLength ?  *what should be here?* : comment);
        }

    class Comment {
    private final String text;

    public Comment(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

The case is next: I pass to the method some comments and max length of comment. The method should take list of comments and next, if comment length > maxTextLength, it returns new comment that is a copy of original comment, but shorter (with maxTextLength amount of characters), and if comment length < maxTextLength, it just returns the same comment (or it can be also a copy with the same amount of characters).

Update:
Example is below - we have (enter it) limit of 30 characters per string and method cuts all characters in each comment if there are more (>) than 30 characters.

**Sample Input:**

30

What a nice view! Where is it *?*

I do not know, I just found it *on the internet!*

Perfect!

**Sample Output:**

What a nice view! Where is it

I do not know, I just found it

Perfect!

Comment: can you give some specific examples of what you expect to be changed into what when passed a specific parameter, what you expect to stay the same (and why), ...

Comment: Do you want to cut your String off to fit a maximum length? If that is the case using replaceAll is really not the way to go.

Comment: Sounds like substring with the conditonal operator `?:` would be better.

Comment: Try to use comment.substr(comment.getText(), maxTextLength)

Comment: Why don't you use `substring`? Sounds like a 100% match for this use case

Comment: Why use `replaceAll` if you don't need to `replace all`?

Comment: From my POV the data itself should only get truncated if need be. Otherwise keep the full text and just truncate for display. This would allow to show the full text when the user hovers or clicks the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never showed the comment class. Can we set the text on a comment? Can we create a new one giving the text on the constructor? I am assuming the latter.

Then replace `*what should be here?*` with

```
 new Comment(comment.getText().substring(0, maxTextLength-3) + "...")
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question and actually I just need this -  new Comment(comment.getText().substring(0, maxTextLength)), but your solution is what I've looked for.

Comment: If you don't use something like an ellipsis (`"…"`) you won't know whether something was truncated

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got your point, but it isn't what I need in my particular task. So I just leave a comment what solution suits to the raised question with its particular case description.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need something like this:

```
public static void handleComments (List<Comment> comments, int maxTextLength) {

    comments.stream()
        .filter(comment -> comment.getText().length() > maxTextLength)
        .forEach(comment -> comment.setText(comment.getText().substring(0, maxTextLength - 1))
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this.  I would opt for the most straight forward.  This method only replaces comments that are too long.

```
class Comment {
    private String text;

    public Comment(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String comment) {
        this.text = comment;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}

List<Comment> comments = List.of(
        new Comment("What a nice view! Where is it ?"),
        new Comment("I do not know, I just found it on the internet!"),
        new Comment("Perfect!"));

comments.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
handleComments(comments, 30);
comments.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
What a nice view! Where is it ?
I do not know, I just found it on the internet!
Perfect!

What a nice view! Where is it 
I do not know, I just found it
Perfect!
```

The handle method.  Just use a loop.  Don't replace the comments if they don't need it or create a new object.  Just update the required text using your `setter`.

```
public static void handleComments(List<Comment> comments,
        int maxTextLength) {
    comments.forEach(com -> {
        String txt = com.getText();
        int len = txt.length();

        if (len > maxTextLength) {
            com.setText(txt.substring(0, maxTextLength));
        }
    });
}
```